# WiFi and Bluetooth Not Working

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I have an iPhone 8. A few months ago the wifi greyed out and the Bluetooth started spinning and not working. After awhile the Bluetooth began to work but not the WiFi. Yesterday I bought a new iwatch. Before I could pair, o had to update my iPhone to version 16 and now Bluetooth is spinning now and won’t pick up anything. I do have a VPN, I have tried factory and settings reset and hard reset.